# NHibernate: How to force ID generation of a child in parent/child relationship

Tags: nhibernate, identity, one-to-many

I have a one-to-many parent/child relationship between a user and a session. Here are the mappings:

```
<class name="ApplicationUser" table="APPLICATION_USER" lazy="true">
    <id name="Id" column="APPLICATION_USER_ID">
         <generator class="guid.comb" />
    </id>
    <property name="UserName" column="USER_NAME" />
    <property name="Password" column="PASSWORD" />
    <bag name="UserSessions" lazy="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan" inverse="true">
        <key column="APPLICATION_USER_ID"></key>
        <one-to-many class="UserSession"></one-to-many>
    </bag>
</class>

<class name="UserSession" table="USER_SESSION" lazy="true">
    <id name="Id" column="USER_SESSION_ID">
         <generator class="guid.comb" />
    </id>
    <property name="Created" column="CREATED" />
    <many-to-one name="ApplicationUser" column="APPLICATION_USER_ID" class="ApplicationUser" unique="true" />
</class>
```

I have a simple method in ApplicationUser that creates the session relationship:

```
public virtual UserSession LogInUser()
{
    UserSession session = new UserSession() { ApplicationUser = this };
    _userSessions.Add(session);
    return session;
}
```

When a user logs in, there are several database interactions that occur, wrapped in a transaction. In addition to creating the new user session, I want to be able to audit that the user has logged in, and include the new session ID with the audit data. However, since the UserSession hasn't been persisted yet, its ID is empty.

I tried saving the ApplicationUser to generate the user session ID:

```
IApplicationUserManager manager = ManagerFactory.GetApplicationUserManager();
ApplicationUser user = manager.GetById(userId);

user.LogInUser();
manager.Save(user);
```

I thought this would work because of the all-delete-orphan cascade setting, but it doesn't. Is there a way to force ID generation before a `Flush()` or transaction commit?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to force ID generation before a Flush() or transaction commit?

No. I would use `<generator class="assigned" />` for the UserSession class and initialize it in the class's constructor.

Also, you might want to think twice about exposing the Password as a property.

Comment: Thanks. The password is encrypted, so it's not as exposed as it looks. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Calling Session.Save (that's NHibernate's Session btw) should generate the ID. That's one of the main reasons for using Guids - they can be generated without going to the database.

If the save doesn't cascade from ApplicationUser, you will just need to manually pass the UserSession to Session.Save. I can't see why this is would be a problem though.

Comment: The problem actually has to do with my architecture. I'm using Data Access Objects (DAOs), so I have one DAO per domain model class (as needed). Session saves are actually abstracted as a method on the DAO. In my code snippet, I save the application manager by calling manager.Save(user), but this Save method is type-specific. I have to instantiate a UserSession DAO to save it separately. It's possible, but I was hoping for something more elegant.

Comment: OK I can see what you're saying. If it was my code I would just create the UserSession DAO and use it to save the session object. I don't see what the problem with this is, and it seems like you would be getting yourself into more headaches if you started changing your mappings or design instead.